# Can we attach excel file in downloaded PDF using mpdf

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I am using mPDF library in Laravel for PDF generation now my requirement is to attach a excel file (from directory at same server) in downloaded PDF file. So if I download the PDF file then I can download that attached excel file offline too (using the downloaded PDF).

Has anyone have experience of it?

Comment: Are you saying you want the content of the Excel file to be inserted into the PDF?

Comment: I want to attached the file in pdf so when I click on that excel icon that excel file with content should be downloaded.

Comment: So you just need to insert a download link into the PDF?

Comment: The same I was thinking but when I click on that link offline then it couldn't download.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do is possible. Have you seen that done before? Sounds like a really easy way to allow malicious files to be embedded without the end user noticing

Comment: I also don't know whether it is possible or not but this is what required.... I have seen the same in screen shot not actual working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149515/discussion-between-raghbendra-nayak-systematix-and-kai).

Comment: Can you edit question with some code you already have there?

Comment: @Tpojka: Honestly I don't know whether is it possible or not?

Comment: Find edit button there and click.

Comment: I know how to edit the question..... my comment was for my question whether is it possible to attach the file in PDF so till now I have tried but I am trying via providing the link on downloaded PDF ...that is working fine now I want to attach whole file there instead of link. Have you ever seen this kind of attachment like full excel file will be available in PDF ?

Comment: @GhostCat: Accepted I will tack-care of this. it should be "Unsalvageable" category .....am I correct ?

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you so much for your guidance and time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include an attachment in a PDF file using mpdf, as documented here https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/pdf-a3-xmp-rdf.html

```
$mpdf->SetAssociatedFiles([[
    'name' => 'public_filename.xml',              //this is the file name that will be displayed to the user
    'mime' => 'text/xml',
    'description' => 'some description',
    'AFRelationship' => 'Alternative',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/../data/xml/test.xml'   //this is the path to the file
]]);
```

if you have your file generated in a variable, you can use `content` instead of `path` and pass directly the file content.

The attached files will be available via the Attachments pane of your pdf reader (Acrobat, Evince). They are not accessible in PDF readers integrated in browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox).

I don't know how to generate a clickable link to the attached file.